# "To live and die against all manner of folks?"

Tags: history

I came across this oath taken by Prince of Wales in the ceremony of investiture,

> I, Charles, Prince of Wales, do become your liege man of life and limb
>   and of earthly worship, and faith and truth I bear unto thee, **to live
>   and die against all manner of folks**.

I don't really understand the latter part of this oath. 'to live and die ' not in the same manner as ordinary folks? Does that mean he is somehow different and superior?

Comment: It's archaic language, but I'm sure _against_ doesn't mean _in a different way from_. It's a promise to defend the monarch to the death against any enemy.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the many uses of the word 'against'.

> 5b. Indicating a possible or anticipated danger: so as to be wary of or alert for.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3754?redirectedFrom=against#eid)

The OED does not list it as archaic but the references for the meaning (5b) finish in 1997 and the one reference I found most suitable to the above question was from 1650:

> 1650   Bp. J. Taylor Rule & Exercises Holy Living ii. §5   **Men stand upon their guard against them** [sc. inquisitions], as they secure their meat against harpies and cats, laying all their counsels and secrets out of their way

Comment: OK, it is plausible that this what *against* means here, but folks, in the usual present-day sense, are not all dangerous enemies, so why would one need to 'be wary of or alert for' 'all manner' of them? The OP seems to have assumed that *folks* has the usual meaning, and was then puzzled by *against*; this answer explains *against* at the cost of making *all manner of folks* more puzzling. We still don't have an explanation that would explain both components and how they work together.